# git: 'remote-https' is not a git command. See 'git --help'

Tags: django, git, github, git-remote, github-for-windows

I have been trying to clone my repository and it shows the following error:-
git: 'remote-https' is not a git command. See 'git --help'

Here is my:-
Clone from

```
https://github.com/NavyaThakur/django-project1
```

To directory

```
C:\Users\91933\github\django-project1
```

I tried reinstalling github desktop but no use.
Please help me through this

Comment: Now it shows that fatal:git clone https is not supported

Answer (score 1):

This error means your git executable was not built with ssl and/or libcurl.

From experience this seems to be a problem on some RedHat based distributions.

If you have admin access just make use you install the correct git client.  If not you will have to build git yourself or install from a repository into your user account (both of which are not trivial, sorry)

Answer (score 0):

Try `git clone https://github.com/YOUR-USERNAME/YOUR-REPOSITORY`

so for you `git clone https://github.com/NavyaThakur/django-project1`

[Git Clone Documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/cloning-a-repository-from-github/cloning-a-repository)